# Is there an easy way to update a series of data frames using a loop?

Tags: r, loops, dataframe

I am looking for a way to run through series of data frames in R in order to restructure them in preparation for pushing them through multiple linear regression models. Here is the basic structure.

Let's say you have 3 data frames:

```
StateList <- c(AL, AR, AZ)
```

Where each state represents a different data frame (same columns with varying record counts). I want to restructure all 3 data frames from its RAW forms of columns to an ETL version where I am only selecting certain columns in a different order then was in the RAW format. I can easily do this by running this:

```
AL <- AL[var5,var3,var2]
AR <- AR[var5,var3,var2]
AZ <- AZ[var5,var3,var2]
```

Is there any easy way that I can loop through all the data frames (which have different names) using a list like in the StateList from above and update all 2 data frames into the ETL format?

I tried doing the below but it doesn't seem to work:

```
VariableList <- c(var5,var3,var2)
for (df in StateList) {
   df[VariableList]}
```

Comment: Consider the extract function, `[`:
`new_stateList <- lapply(stateList, "[", VariableList)`

Answer (score 1):

Something like this?

```
library(dplyr)

data(mtcars)
df1 <- mtcars %>% filter(cyl == 4)
df2 <- mtcars %>% filter(cyl == 6)
df3 <- mtcars %>% filter(cyl == 8)

df_names <- c("df1", "df2", "df3")

df_list <- lapply(df_names, get)
names(df_list) <- df_names
```

You can then use `lapply` or `map` functions to apply whatever function you require to each of the list elements (which are your data frames).

Comment: How does this answer OP's question? OP already has a list of data frames.

Comment: Yes, but the list has a structure which you do not want: `StateList <- c(AL, AR, AZ)` returns one list with the data frame rows as list items. And it does not return a list with the 3 DFs as list elements.

Answer (score 0):

Add the dataframe in a list, you can iterate over them using `lapply`, arrange the data in a specific order and do whatever tasks you would like to do on it.

```
StateList <- list(AL, AR, AZ)
VariableList <- c("var5","var3","var2")

result <- lapply(StateList, function(x) {
              new_data <- new_data <- data[, VariableList]
              #Add code to perform on each dataframe
              #....
})
```